# ngif tagged elements sometimes return null even when change detection is triggered manually

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

My tests sometimes fails, because an element does not exist when queried in a test. From my understanding this shouldn't happen because before the element is queried the change detection is triggered by fixture.detectChanges(). So in theory the ngIf directive should be checked during change detection and when checked by the test, it should already be done checking. However sometimes this is not the case.

The error output in that case is: Type Error: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null

Test

```
it('when blue pen should be clickable', () => {
                // any variable modification
                const openInputSampleSpy = spyOn(component, 'openInputSample');

                fixture.detectChanges();
                const bluePen = componentElement.query(By.css('.pen-blue')).nativeElement;
                bluePen.click();

                expect(openInputSampleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

HTML

```
<button (click)="openInputSample()"
                *ngIf="isBluePenVisible"
                class="pen-blue right-button" [@fadeInOut]>
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's strange. Try making it explicit like so:

```
it('when blue pen should be clickable', () => {
                // any variable modification
                const openInputSampleSpy = spyOn(component, 'openInputSample');

                fixture.detectChanges();
                componentElement.isBluePenVisible = true; // add these 2 lines
                fixture.detectChanges();
                const bluePen = componentElement.query(By.css('.pen-blue')).nativeElement;
                bluePen.click();

                expect(openInputSampleSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: Sadly the same issue. The error occurs in like 1 out of 100 cases.